# How to exit a macro in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I'm trying to include an instruction for the script in Google Sheets to exit and not run any of the stuff that comes after the if statement.

I tried `return` and `System.exit(myMacro)` but they do not work. Is there any other instruction?

```
if (myVar == 1)
{
    myVar = myVar + 1;
}
else
{
   //code to exit console application run
}
// More code after the if statement
```

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake with `return`. Consider to add a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop the execution of a Script use the [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement. Example:

```
if (myVar == 1)
{
    myVar = myVar + 1;
}
else
{
   //code to exit console application run
   return;
}
// More code after the if statement
```

Comment: Thank you! I made a mistake with the semicolon. It worked perfectly.